# Error :Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I wrote services class.

```
 public partial class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        #region Constants

        private const string PRODUCTVARIANTPRICERANGE_PATTERN_KEY = "Nop.productVariantPriceRange.";
        #endregion

        #region Fields


        private readonly IRepository<ProductVariantPriceRange> _productVariantPriceRangeRepository;

        public ProductService(ICacheManager cacheManager,

            IRepository<ProductVariantPriceRange> productVariantPriceRangeRepository,
            )
        {

            this._productVariantPriceRangeRepository = productVariantPriceRangeRepository;

        }

        #endregion
```

Then write a function

```
 public virtual void CheckProductVariantPriceRange(int productVariantPriceRangeId)
        {
            bool flage=true;
            var query = _productVariantPriceRangeRepository.Table;

               query = query.Where(m => m.ProductVariantId.Contains(productVariantPriceRangeId));


            var ProductVariantPriceRangeS = query.ToList();
            if (ProductVariantPriceRangeS.Count == 0)
            {
                flage = false;
            }

        }
```

but It occur the flowing error..

1. `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'`
2. 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 
       'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

I don't know what is this error.
How can I solve this..
Plz help

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? : `query = query.Where(m => m.ProductVariantId.Contains(productVariantPriceRangeId));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProductVariantId` property is not a collection, it's a single value. You should compare the value in the property for each record to the desired value:

```
query = query.Where(m => m.ProductVariantId == productVariantPriceRangeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Contains` method call. In other words, replace:

```
query = query.Where(m => 
    m.ProductVariantId.Contains(productVariantPriceRangeId));
```

with

```
query = query.Where(m => m.ProductVariantId == productVariantPriceRangeId);
```